# Drag Node with Dagre-D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, directed-graph, dagre-d3

I implemented the functionality, that you can pan and zoom the whole graph but also being able to drag one specific node. My problem at this point is, that I can't find a way how to update the edges while dragging a node.

Here you can find a minimal setup:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJZrxm

In:

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  // find edges which link to the currently moved node
} 
function dragged(d) {
  // update edges
}
```

Of course this behavior should also work with much more nodes and edges.

Comment: From https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/issues/74 motoz`s answer: working example: http://jsfiddle.net/egfx43hs/11/